# Query by Date in Java JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

How is it possible to query for DateTime in MySQL in JPA? The variable before is a Date() object in milliseconds. I would do something like the following:

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<Entry> findAllBefore(Long before, Integer nEntries)
{

  CriteriaBuilder builder = this.getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
  CriteriaQuery<Entry> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Entry.class);

  Root root = criteriaQuery.from(Entry.class);
  criteriaQuery.select( root );

  // seems not to work
  criteriaQuery.where( builder.lessThan( root.get( "start" ) , before ) ); 

  TypedQuery<Entry> typedQuery = this.getEntityManager()
     .createQuery(criteriaQuery)
     .setMaxResults(nEntries)

  return typedQuery.getResultList();
}
```

I want to have all Entries from the corresponding table where the DateTime column "start" is before the value in the variable 'before'.

Comment: what about you needed exactly?

Comment: I edited my post. see last sentence, please

Comment: I think you have to convert your long to `Date` object.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but without any success

Comment: "without success" ? do people have to guess what that means? some error, some exception? Pass a java.util.Date in as a start

Comment: using a java.util.Date is the way it works for the rest of the Java engineering world, so I'm sure with a little bit of effort to fix a lingering mistake it can start to work for you to.

Comment: of course it works as suggested. thanks. the problem was on a different part of my code. sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you use a predicate?
maybe there will be compilation errors in my reply because i am not on my pc now, but with this it should be pretty straightforward to find your way through. 
First in the method signature I would pass a date (or possibly convert the long to date inside your method).

After you have a date :

```
    CriteriaBuilder builder = this.getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Entry> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Entry.class);
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
ParameterExpression<Date> param = builder.parameter(Date.class, "start");
predicates.add(builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("beforeDate"), param));   criteriaQuery.select(customer)
        .where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
"EntityManagerVariableName".createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

Comment: this was really helpful. Leads me to the heard of my problem. I messed things up while having multiple 'where' statements. thanks

Comment: @Xear if the answer solves the problem please do vote it. thanks